# How to create a submodule in Vuex with vuex-module-decorators?

Tags: vuex, vuex-modules

I'd like to have a `project` module in Vuex, which has sub-modules for `props`, `document`, `author`, and so on (so project.props, project.document, etc). I'm starting to use https://championswimmer.in/vuex-module-decorators/ and from the doc it's not clear how to set up sub-modules. Is there a simple example or some doc I missed?

I want the store to be laid out with the document (etc.) inside the project because I'll save and load entire projects via my API.